# How to sum the quantity grouped by more than one field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

How do i sum the 'qty' field grouped by [pid][sid][eid][dbid] fields:

```
d = [
   {'pid': 146, 'sid': 6, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 10},
   {'pid': 146, 'sid': 6, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 20},
   {'pid': 232, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 1},
   {'pid': 232, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 1},
   {'pid': 146, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 100},
   {'pid': 146, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 100},
   ]

# non-working code
sum_of_qty = []
for row in d:
    sum_of_qty[[row['pid']][row['sid']][row['eid']][row['dbid']]] += row['qty']
```

This is the final result i want:

```
sum_of_qty = [
    {'pid': 146, 'sid': 6, 'eid': 6121, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 30},
    {'pid': 232, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6121, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 2},
    {'pid': 146, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6121, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 200}
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
d = [
  {'pid': 146, 'sid': 6, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 10},
  {'pid': 146, 'sid': 6, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 20},
  {'pid': 232, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 1},
  {'pid': 232, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 1},
  {'pid': 146, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 100},
  {'pid': 146, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 100},
]
new_d = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(d, key=lambda x:[x['pid'], x['sid']])]
final_result = [{**i[0], **{'qty':sum(b['qty'] for b in i)}} for i in new_d]
```

Output:

```
[{'pid': 146, 'sid': 6, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 30}, {'pid': 232, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 2}, {'pid': 146, 'sid': 56, 'eid': 6212, 'dbid': 1, 'qty': 200}]
```

Comment: thank you. I don't completely understand the codes but it works.

Comment: Your code works in python v3.6.4. But when i  migrate to python v3.4 (our prod server), it complains about the double asterisks **, giving me an error message, "Invalid syntax". how would you rewrite this to work with v3.4. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm putting the link to the solution for v3.4 in case someone might need it in the future: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297859/double-asterisks-error-invalid-syntax/50298345#50298345]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sum_of_qty = []
temp = {} # temporary datastructure

for element in d:
    tup = (element['pid'],element['sid'],element['eid'],element['dbid']) # tuple
    if tup not in temp:
       temp[tup] = element['qty']
    else:
       temp[tup] += element['qty']

for key in temp:
   dic = {'pid':key[0],'sid': key[1], 'eid': key[2], 'dbid': key[3], 'qty': temp[key]}
   sum_of_qty.append(dic)
```

Comment: Thanks. Easy for newbie like me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

based on [Ajax1234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7326738/ajax1234) answer, but more readable:

```
import itertools
from collections import ChainMap

sum_of_qty = [
    list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(d, key=lambda x: [x[k] for k in x if k != 'qty'])
]

for i, item in enumerate(sum_of_qty):
    sum_of_qty[i] = dict(ChainMap(*item))
    sum_of_qty[i]['qty'] = sum(map(lambda x: x['qty'], item))
```