# Double asterisks error: Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Original Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033119/how-to-sum-the-quantity-grouped-by-more-than-one-field)

I want to sum the [qty] based on [pid][dbid][eid][sid].

this code works on v3.6.4 but when i migrate to v3.4, then i got an error message:

```
new_d =  [ [{'pid': 146, 'dbid': 1, 'eid': 6212, 'qty': 10, 'sid': 6}, {'pid': 146, 'dbid': 1, 'eid': 6212, 'qty': 20, 'sid': 6}],
           [{'pid': 232, 'dbid': 1, 'eid': 6212, 'qty': 1, 'sid': 56}, {'pid': 232, 'dbid': 1, 'eid': 6212, 'qty': 1, 'sid': 56}],
           [{'pid': 146, 'dbid': 1, 'eid': 6212, 'qty': 100, 'sid': 56}, {'pid': 146, 'dbid': 1, 'eid': 6212, 'qty': 100, 'sid': 56}]]

final_result = [{**i[0], **{'qty':sum(b['qty'] for b in i)}} for i in new_d]
                  ^
       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That syntax doesn't exist in Python 3.4. You may want to consider using Pandas or some other library to simplify operations on table-like structures if you're going to be doing many of them.

Comment: Thanks, would you know how to rewrite this? sorry i didn't write this line of code, someone helped me. I don't do this type of operations very often.

Comment: Just for information on when it was introduced: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Comment: For reference, it was added in version 3.5 [Additional Unpacking Generalizatoins](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`**` can be used to unpack dictionaries into keyword arguments in function calls. Beginning with python 3.5, [PEP 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) was added to the language. This expands the places where you can unpack tuples (`*some_tuple`) and dictionaries (`**some_dict`).

In

```
{**i[0], **{'qty':sum(b['qty'] for b in i)}}
```

`i[0]` is the first `dict` in the list and `{'qty':sum(b['qty'] for b in i)}` is a `dict` with one key that sums the `'qty'` values in the list. The `**` operator unpacks both dictionaries and since the dictionary constructor now supports an arbitrary number of unpackings, the two dictionaries are merged into one.

This can all be done with a function for python 3.4 and earlier

```
def d_summary(d_list):
    summary = d_list[0].copy()
    summary['qty'] = sum(b['qty'] for b in d_list)
    return summary

final_result = [d_summary(i) for i in new_d]
```